# RecyclerView filtering updates recycler view error

Tags: android, list, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a recycler view in which I display phone contacts. You can select or deselect a contact in the list thanks to a checkbox. The recycler view is displayed on an activity. Navigating to that activity, I transfer all contacts that have been selected before and when I'm displaying the list, I compare the phone contacts to the selected ones in order to select them by default in the list. So I have  two lists passed to the adapter: ***phone contacts list*** and ***selected contacts list***. I let the user filter the contacts list by display name so I bind  a TextWatcher event on the EditText, which reload the recyclerview after the text has changed. But the problem is when the user starts to filter, the selected contacts list is being populated from nowhere and I got all the phone contacts in the selected contacts list.... Very strange...

Here is the adapter:

```
public class ContactsChooserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactChooserViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<Contact> mContacts;
private ArrayList<Contact> mSelectedContacts;
private OnContactSelectionListener mContactListener;

public ContactsChooserAdapter(ArrayList<Contact> contacts, ArrayList<Contact> selectedContacts)
{
    mContacts = contacts;
    mSelectedContacts = selectedContacts;
}

public void setOnContactSelectionListener(OnContactSelectionListener listener)
{
    mContactListener = listener;
}

@Override
public ContactChooserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.contacts_chooser_list_item, parent, false);
    ContactChooserViewHolder holder = new ContactChooserViewHolder(v);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactChooserViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Contact contact = getContacts().get(position);
    if(isAlreadySelected(contact)){
        holder.mChoosed.setChecked(true);
    }else{
        holder.mChoosed.setChecked(false);
    }

    holder.mContactDisplayName.setText(contact.getDisplayName());
    holder.mContactPhoneNumber.setText(contact.getPhoneNumbers().get(0));
    if(mContactListener != null) {
        holder.bind(contact, mContactListener);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return getContacts().size();
}

/**
 * Method which allows to check whenever a contact is already selected in a list or not.
 * @param contact
 * @return
 */
private boolean isAlreadySelected(Contact contact){
    boolean alreadySelected = false;
    if(getAlreadySelectedContacts() != null){
        System.out.println("ALready selected contact list: "+ getAlreadySelectedContacts().size());
        for(Contact c : getAlreadySelectedContacts()){
            if(c.getId() == contact.getId()){
                alreadySelected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return alreadySelected;
}


public ArrayList<Contact> getContacts() {
    return mContacts;
}

public void setContacts(ArrayList<Contact> mContacts) {
    this.mContacts = mContacts;
}


public ArrayList<Contact> getAlreadySelectedContacts() {
    return mSelectedContacts;
}

public void setAlreadySelectedContacts(ArrayList<Contact> selectedContacts) {
    this.mSelectedContacts = selectedContacts;
}
```

}

Here is the activity:

```
 public class ContactsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<Contact> mSelectedContacts;
private ArrayList<Contact> mPhoneContacts;
private RecyclerView mContactsList;
private BatifyTextViewBold mContactsNbLabel;
private BatifyEditText mSearchEditText;
private ContactsChooserAdapter mContactsChooserAdapter;
private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
private RelativeLayout mCancelBtn;
private RelativeLayout mFinishBtn;
private ImageView mSearchIcon;
private RelativeLayout mListHeader;
private RelativeLayout mSearchLayout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.batifyGreen));
    }

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    ArrayList<Contact> transmittedContacts = bundle.getParcelableArrayList(GlobalVariables.CONTACTS_SELECTED_CONTACTS_LABEL);
    mSelectedContacts = new ArrayList<>();
    if(transmittedContacts != null) {
        mSelectedContacts.addAll(transmittedContacts);
    }

    mContactsList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.contactsList);
    mContactsNbLabel = (BatifyTextViewBold)findViewById(R.id.contactNbSelectedTv);

    if(getSelectedContacts() == null){
        mContactsNbLabel.setText("0 contact ");
    }else{
        mContactsNbLabel.setText(getSelectedContacts().size() + (getSelectedContacts().size() > 1 ?  " contacts " : " contact "));
    }

    mFinishBtn = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.finishContactsBtn);
    mFinishBtn.setOnClickListener(finishChoosingContactsListener);

    mCancelBtn = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.cancelContactsBtn);
    mCancelBtn.setOnClickListener(cancelChoosingContactsListener);

    mSearchIcon = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);
    mSearchIcon.setOnClickListener(searchListener);

    mListHeader = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.listHeader);
    mListHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mSearchLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.searchLayout);
    mSearchLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    mSearchEditText = (BatifyEditText)findViewById(R.id.searchContactsEditText);
    mSearchEditText.addTextChangedListener(searchViewWatcher);



    requestPermissionForContactsAndProcess();
}


/**
 * Method that requests the permission to access contacts.
 */
public void requestPermissionForContactsAndProcess() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
            Tools.showPopUpCallBack(this, "Information", getString(R.string.contactRationalMessage), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
                    {
                        requestPermissionForContactsAndProcess();
                    }
                }
            });

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, GlobalVariables.CONTACTS_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    }else{
        getAllContactsAndDisplay();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case GlobalVariables.CONTACTS_PERMISSIONS: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getAllContactsAndDisplay();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Method which allows to display a contacts list
 */
public void displayContactList(){
    mContactsChooserAdapter = new ContactsChooserAdapter(getPhoneContacts(), getSelectedContacts());
    mContactsChooserAdapter.setOnContactSelectionListener(contactSelectionListener);
    mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mContactsList.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
    mContactsList.setAdapter(mContactsChooserAdapter);
}

/**
 * Method that will retrieve all contacts.
 */
private void getAllContactsAndDisplay()
{
    mPhoneContacts = new ArrayList<>();
    Contact contact;
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                contact = new Contact();
                contact.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
                contact.setDisplayName(displayName);

                Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id},
                        null);
                if (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    contact.getPhoneNumbers().add(phoneNumber);
                }

                phoneCursor.close();

                getPhoneContacts().add(contact);
            }
        }
    }
    displayContactList();
}


/**
 * Method which allow to finish and close the activity. It returns a result.
 */
public void finishedChoosingContacts()
{
    Intent intent= new Intent();
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(GlobalVariables.CONTACTS_SELECTED_CONTACTS_LABEL, getSelectedContacts());
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}


/**
 * Listener which allows to select and deselect a contact in a list.
 */
private OnContactSelectionListener contactSelectionListener = new OnContactSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onContactSelected(Contact contact) {
        if(getSelectedContacts() == null){
            setSelectedContacts(new ArrayList<Contact>());
        }
        getSelectedContacts().add(contact);
        mContactsNbLabel.setText(getSelectedContacts().size() + (getSelectedContacts().size() > 1 ? " contacts " : " contact "));
    }

    @Override
    public void onContactDeSelected(Contact contact) {
        int indexToDelete = -1;
        for(Contact c : getSelectedContacts()){
            if(c.getId() == contact.getId()){
                indexToDelete = getSelectedContacts().indexOf(c);
                break;
            }
        }

        if(indexToDelete > -1) {
            getSelectedContacts().remove(indexToDelete);
            mContactsNbLabel.setText(getSelectedContacts().size() + (getSelectedContacts().size() > 1 ? " contacts " : " contact "));
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Listener which is fired when the search edit text value is changing.
 */
private TextWatcher searchViewWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        filterListAndUpdate(s.toString());
    }
};

/**
 * method used to filter and update the list
 * @param searchedValue
 */
private void filterListAndUpdate(String searchedValue)
{
    ArrayList<Contact> associatedSearch = new ArrayList<>();
    if(!"".equals(searchedValue) && searchedValue != null) {
        for (Contact c : getPhoneContacts()) {
            if (c.getDisplayName().toUpperCase().startsWith(searchedValue.toUpperCase())) {
                associatedSearch.add(c);
            }
        }
        ((ContactsChooserAdapter)mContactsList.getAdapter()).setContacts(associatedSearch);
    }else{
        ((ContactsChooserAdapter)mContactsList.getAdapter()).setContacts(getPhoneContacts());
    }

    mContactsList.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
}


/**
 * Listener that allows to fire the search listener.
 */
private View.OnClickListener searchListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mListHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mSearchLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
};


/**
 * Listener which is fired when the user cancels the contacts selection.
 */
private View.OnClickListener cancelChoosingContactsListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       finish();
    }
};

/**
 * Listener which id fired when the user finishes selecting contacts.
 */
private View.OnClickListener finishChoosingContactsListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finishedChoosingContacts();
    }
};



public ArrayList<Contact> getSelectedContacts() {
    return mSelectedContacts;
}

public void setSelectedContacts(ArrayList<Contact> mSelectedContacts) {
    this.mSelectedContacts = mSelectedContacts;
}

public ArrayList<Contact> getPhoneContacts() {
    return mPhoneContacts;
}
```

}

Comment: It seems that in your ```filterListAndUpdate``` the ```else``` statement is executed. Can you check if the ```searchedValue``` is the right one.

Comment: Thnaks for the response. Yes it's right one and the else statement is not executed... Since I filter, The ***mSelectedContactslist*** is populated with everything in ***mContacts*** list. Either the checkbox is checked for every contacts. Maybe there is something wrong with notifyDataSetChanges...

Comment: I don't think it's notifyDataSetChanges issue, one more quick tip, if you use instant run, you might want to clean/build again, I had issues with it before. Also can you add the whole code from your activity ?

Comment: I've just clean it and rebuild it.. Same issue.. Yep. i'm gonna update the post